# Massive time increase when segmenting column and writing parquet file

Tags: pyspark

I work with clinical data, so I apologize that I can't display any output, as it is HIPAA regulated, but I'll do my best to fill in any gaps.

I am a recent graduate in data science, and I never really spent much time working with any spark system, but I am now in my new role. We are working on collecting output from a function that I will call udf_function, which takes a clinical note (`report`) from a physician and returns output that the function defines from the python function `call_function`. Here is the code that I use to complete this task

```
def call_function(report):

    //python code that generates a list of a,b,c, which I 
      join together to return a string of the combined list items

    a=  ",".join(a)
    b= ",".join(b)
    c= ",".join(c)
    return [a,b,c]


udf_function= udf(lambda y: call_function(y), ArrayType(StringType()))

mid_frame = df.select('report',
                       udf_function('report').alias('udf_output')
                     )
```

This returns an array of length 3, which contains strings about the information returned from the function. On a selection of 25,000 records, I was able to complete the run on a 30 node cluster on GCP (20 workers, 10 preemptive) in just a little over 3 hours the other day.

I changed my code a bit to parse out the three objects from the array, as the three objects contains different types of information that we want to further analyze, which I'll call `a`,`b`,`c` (again, sorry if this is vague; I'm trying to keep the actual data as surface level as possible). The previous 3 hour run didn't write out any files, as I was was testing how long the system would take.

```
output = mid_frame.select('report',
                           mid_frame['udf_output'].getItem(0).alias('a'),
                           mid_frame['udf_output'].getItem(1).alias('b'),
                           mid_frame['udf_output'].getItem(2).alias('c')
                          )
output_frame.show()
output_frame.write.parquet(data_bucket)
```

This task of parsing the output and writing the files took an additional 48 hours. I think I could stomach this time lost if I was dealing with HUGE files, but the output is 4 parquet files which come out to 24.06 MB total. Looking at the job logs, the writing process itself took just about 20 hours.

Obviously I have introduced some extreme inefficiency, but I'm since I'm new to this system and style of work, I'm not sure where I have gone awry.

Thank you to all that can offer some advice or guidance on this!

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what `report` might be and what the return would be from the function

This is a sentence I wrote myself, and thus, is not pulled from any real record

```
report = 'The patient showed up to the hospital, presenting with a heart attack and diabetes'

   \\ code

return ['heart attack, diabetes','myocardial infarction, diabetes mellatus', 'X88989,B898232']
```

where the first item is any actual string in the sentence that is tagged by the code, the second item is the professional medical equivalent, and the third item is simply a code which helps us find diagnosis hierarchy between other codes

Comment: how you are creating list and what's the actual source of your data. can you be able to demonstrate with some fictitious data as a sample. It will really help to understand the problem. Thanks

Comment: if you only write 4 output files you probably only use 4 cores rather than all 30. You can check this in the SparkUI.
Does the show take 3 hours or the write.parquet? Because of lazy execution you are actually calculating things twice

Comment: @Paul, for the initial 3 hour trial, I only show the data frame. I would have assumed that the lazy execution would have called the udf function once during the show, and then have that data set once we go to write. You're saying that it will execute once for show and then again for write?

Comment: @vikrantrana I just edited the post to give a better example of what the the input and output looks like

Comment: a show might not cause full calculation but rather only calculates on some partitions s.t. the requested 20 rows can be shown. This might explain the difference

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 4 parquet file outputs, that says your partition is too small, try repartition before you write out. For example:

```
output_frame= output_frame.repartition(500)
output_frame.write.parquet(data_bucket)
```